# How to get MAX value from Dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

I have

```
Dictionary<Guid, DateTime> d = new Dictionary<Guid, DateTime>();
```

How I can get an `Guid` which has `MAX` value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Max() of alphanumeric value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268605/get-max-of-alphanumeric-value)

Comment: Please try to do your own research before asking question on SO.

Comment: Since "GUID" stands for "globally unique identifier," it seems incredibly odd that you would want a "maximum" value at all. A GUID is used because of its uniqueness; I cannot think of a real world application where it makes sense to think of them as ordered at all.

Comment: I think perhaps you miss the point entirely jpmc26. Suppose for instance I have var fooDict = new Dictionary<string, int>(); where the string value is a GUID and I want to know which which kvp has the highest int value (using MoreLinq): var biggestIntKey = fooDict .MaxBy(kvp => kvp.Value).Key; var biggestInt = fooDict [biggestIntKey]. And I think just about anyone reading SO knows what a GUID is. Not helpful.

Comment: Exactly same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2805703/465053).

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Since this was the accepted answer, I'll try to cover every possible meaning of the question:

```cs
var dict = 
    new Dictionary<string, int> 
    { 
        ["b"] = 3, 
        ["a"] = 4 
    };

// greatest key
var maxKey = dict.Keys.Max(); // "b"

// greatest value
var maxValue = dict.Values.Max(); // 4

// key of the greatest value
// 4 is the greatest value, and its key is "a", so "a" is the answer.
var keyOfMaxValue =
    dict.MaxBy(entry => entry.Value).Key; // "a"

// Note: On .NET < 6, MaxBy is not available. You can use:
var keyOfMaxValue = 
    dict.Aggregate((x, y) => x.Value > y.Value ? x : y).Key; // "a"
```

Note: the question has `System.Guid` as the key type. It might not make sense to ask "what is the greatest GUID", since they are simply intended to be unique values, rather than represent any orderable concept. Nonetheless, the above code will work with any type that supports the `>` operator, `string` and `int` being chosen here for conciseness.

Comment: But he asked for the Key which has the max Value. This just gives us the max Key, so it's the wrong thing.

Comment: if someone wants the max Value, then they can use d.Values.Max();

Answer (score 55):

This works great.  It will return the GUID for the MAX date.

```
Dictionary<Guid, DateTime> d = new Dictionary<Guid, DateTime>(); 
var guidForMaxDate = d.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == d.Values.Max()).Key;
```

Comment: Nice, though I'd get that `d.Values.Max()` out into a variable in advance, otherwise it'll probably repeat that search for Max() in every single iteration.

Answer (score 12):

```
            var maxGuid = Guid.Empty;
            var maxDateTime = DateTime.MinValue;
            foreach (var kvp in d)
            {
                if (kvp.Value > maxDateTime)
                {
                    maxGuid = kvp.Key;
                    maxDateTime = kvp.Value;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Guid of max date is: " + maxGuid.ToString());
```

Comment: Re-reading the question, I think this is the correct interpretation, and the only answer that gives the correct result (although I suspect it could be made shorter with LINQ, it won't be any faster than this explicit loop).

Comment: @BenVoigt explicit loop is best deal here in terms of clarity. Another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2805703/465053) with some very good answers. The accepted answer in this post claims to have single scan using LINQ.

Answer (score 6):

Ordering your data in the first place could be one solution.

```
var maxGuid = d.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault().Key;
```

Comment: Sorting the entire list is a bit expensive in comparison to just returning the highest value

Comment: OrderByDescending returns an IOrderedEnumerable (which is an IEnumerable exposing more ordering options, like ThenBy or ThenByDescending). This code will only go through the data once, to get the highest value, then it will output the first one. It will not reorder ALL the list unless you materialize it and store it somewhere, like in a variable, with .ToArray(), for example. FirstOrDefault does nothing more than take the first item if it exists, and does not iterate over the values. How is it different than other answers? Do you have any idea how linq .Max or .MaxBy extensions work?

Answer (score 5):

Guid implements IComparable, so:

```
d.Keys.Max()
```

Also it is not clear why one would want to do so...

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. The following code (using MoreLinq) did the job though:

```
var fooDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var keyForBiggest = fooDict.MaxBy(kvp => kvp.Value).Key;
var biggestInt = fooDict[keyForBiggest];
```

Answer (score 3):

By using LINQ on dictionary.

```
var MaximumValue = dict.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.Equals(dict.Values.Max()));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Another way might helps to get Single KeyValuePair.**

```
KeyValuePair<char, int> GuidKeyPair = guidDict.FirstOrDefault( MaxGuid => MaxGuid.Value == guidDict.Values.Max());
```