# How sort Dictionary by 2 criterias and subcriteria in c#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I want to sort `myDictionary` first by Key and then by Value.

```
Dictionary<int, double> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, double>()
{
    {1,514},
    {2,509},
    {3,510},
    {4,509},
    {5,517},
    {6,512},
    {7,514},
    {8,511}
}
```

I need to find min and max `Value`, then to sort it by `Key`.

```
var orderedDict = myObjectDictionary
       .OrderByDescending(a => a.Value)
       .ThenBy(b => b.Key);
```

But I need to find this object with min `Value` farthest(using `Key`) from object with max `Value`. If there is two object with min/max `Value` to get farthest(using `Key`) one from opposite object(min/max).

After that I need to look for object near to min/max and if their Values are near to min/max Values and they are farthest to get them.

**In this case:
Max= 5, 517
Min= 3, 510**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: other ways to get max value https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290838/how-to-get-max-value-from-dictionary

Comment: @PeterCsala my question is how can i achive this result (In this case: Max= 5, 517 Min= 3, 510)? Can someone provide a code example or somethin to show?

Comment: I can see that 517 is the largest value, that's why 5, 517 is the max. But there are two 509 values at key 2 and 4. So why is 3, 510 is your min?

Comment: Because i can not get min and max if they are next to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requirement: *Can't get a **min** and  a **max** if they are next to each other*.

- In the following solution I've assumed that `myDictionary` keys are incremented by 1.

You can have the desired output with the following code:

```
var groupedByValues = myDictionary.ToLookup(p => p.Value, p => p.Key);

var orderByValues = from item in groupedByValues
                    orderby item.Key ascending
                    select (Value:item.Key, Indexes: item.ToList());
var orderedByValues = orderByValues.ToList();

var maxCandidates = orderByValues.Last();
(int Key, double Value) max = (maxCandidates.Indexes.First(), maxCandidates.Value);
(int Key, double Value)? min = null;

foreach(var item in orderedByValues)
{
    if (item.Indexes.Any(idx => Math.Abs(idx - max.Key) == 1))
        continue;
    else
    {
        min = (item.Indexes.First(), item.Value);
        break;
    }
};
```

---

```
var groupedByValues = myDictionary.ToLookup(p => p.Value, p => p.Key);
```

- Here we create groups based on the value, the `groupedByValues` looks like this:

```
514: 1,7
509: 2,4
510: 3
517: 5
512: 6
511: 8
```

---

```
var orderByValues = from item in groupedByValues
                    orderby item.Key ascending
                    select (Value:item.Key, Indexes: item.ToList());

var orderedByValues = orderByValues.ToList();
```

- Here we simply order the previous collection by its keys
- The `orderByValues` is just a query, the `orderedByValues` is its materialized form:

```
509: 2,4
510: 3
511: 8
512: 6
514: 1,7
517: 5
```

---

```
var maxCandidates = orderByValues.Last();
(int Key, double Value) max = (maxCandidates.Indexes.First(), maxCandidates.Value);
(int Key, double Value)? min = null;
```

- By issuing the `orderByValues.Last` command we get the highest value

  - The highest value can be present multiple times that's why we have `Indexes`
  - I've picked the first index from `Indexes` but you might need to alter this logic based on your requirements
- We convert the `maxCandidates` into the expected output format
- We create a `min` variable, which is nullable to be able to initialize it

---

```
foreach(var item in orderedByValues)
{
    if (item.Indexes.Any(idx => Math.Abs(idx - max.Key) == 1))
        continue;
    else
    {
        min = (item.Indexes.First(), item.Value);
        break;
    }
};
```

- Here we iterate through the `orderedByValues` collection in order to find the first `min` which satisfies all requirements
- We are checking the distance between the max Key and the min candidate's indexes

  - If any of the indexes is next to the max key, then we continue searching
  - If none of the indexes is next to the max key, then we have found the min